# Call JSONArray items in ListView in android

Tags: android

Hi need to call JSONArray 
`{"questions":{"poll_id":"1","user_id":"110","questions":"Captial of USA?"},"answers":[{"poll_id":"1","answer_id":"1","answer":"New York"},{"poll_id":"1","answer_id":"2","answer":"New Jersy"}]}` in to the listview, im new to the android plz.... help me in this.

I got questions part, but i need to show answers part in the listview.

Comment: firstly, thats not a valid json. secondly, I'm sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Raunak JSON is working fine. I dont know why you have mentioned that it is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Its really simple JSON response.

- To parse JSON response, there are 2 classes mainly useful: [`JSONObject`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html), [`JSONArray`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) and use methods of these classes: [`getJSONObject()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject%28java.lang.String%29), [`getJSONArray()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONArray%28java.lang.String%29), and [`getString()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: What! response vs reponse

Comment: @Sydwell apologies! Details and syntax errors are corrected. Feel free to ask me if you are still facing any issue!